# most frequent value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Write an SQL statement to show the SKU and SKU_Description of the item ordered the
most frequently (most orders, not most total quantity).

I tried that but I did not get the right answer ( compared when I did it manually)

```
SELECT order_item.SKU,SKU_Description,COUNT(order_item.SKU) as 'Value'
FROM Order_Item
INNER JOIN SKU_Data
ON Order_Item.SKU=SKU_Data.SKU
GROUP BY order_item.SKU,SKU_Description
Order by 'Value' DESC
Limit 1;
```

Here the different tables available

```
Inventory (WarehouseID,SKU,SKU_Description,QuantityOnHand,QuantityOnOrder)

Order_Item(OrderNumber,SKU,Quantity,Price,ExtendedPrice)

Retail_order(OrderNumber,StoreNumber,StoreZip,OrderMonth,OrderYear,OrderTotal)

SKU_Data(SKU,SKU_Description,Department,Buyer)

Warehouse(WarehouseCity,WarehouseState,Manager,SquareFeet)
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from `'Value'` - I think they are being misinterpreted in the `GROUP BY`. When quoting aliases they should be quoted with backticks `\`Value\`` but that one does not need them.

Comment: Tank you. I will try that